# how do i make my html Navigation bar header mobile friendly

Tags: html, mobile, navigationbar

Hey guys the rest of my page is mobile friendly except my Navigation bar. Can someone correct me on my mistake. On the web platform there is nothing wrong with the navigation bad but on the mobile platform it just does not fit in with the rest of the page. I have included the CSS and HTML Code below.
I can not figure out how to make it mobile friendly and it just sticks out and makes the mobile page bigger.

```
    <header>
        <div class="navigation-bar">
            <div id="navigation-container">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Trulli" width="400" height="80">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.mhric.org/about/about-mhric">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.mhric.org/services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.mhric.org/training">Training</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.mhric.org/directory">Departments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.mhric.org/resources">Recources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.mhric.org/career-opportunities">Career Opportunities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.mhric.org/our-partners">Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.mhric.org/links/links">Vendor Links</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

```css
#navigation-container {
 width: 1600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100px;
  }
  
  .navigation-bar {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align:center;
  }
  .navigation-bar img{
  float:left;
  }
  .navigation-bar ul {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
  }
  
  .navigation-bar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline;
  }
  
  .navigation-bar li a {
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 70px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  #menu {
 float: right;
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: You might want to check media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries